# exim4 I don't understand why my queue list fills again

Tags: email, email-server, exim

I have stopped `exim4` by `/etc/init.d/exim4 stop` but when I run `exim -bp` my queue list continues to fill. I don't understand why, can someone explain what I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the `SMTP` daemon is not running (i.e. **exim4** executed with the `-bd` option) and hence no messages from the network are added to the queue, **exim4** can still accept messages from local users in three other ways:

- when a user calls `/usr/sbin/exim4 -bm` (default action),
- when a user calls `/usr/sbin/exim4 -bs`,
- when a user calls `/usr/sbin/exim4 -bS`

These three modes of operation differ only in the way messages are submitted, you can find the details in [Exim's manual](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-how_exim_receives_and_delivers_mail.html#SECID13).

What matters for you is that messages can still come in, but since no **queue runner** (**exim4** executed with the `-q` option) is active, they will never leave it: they will never be delivered to local mailboxes or sent to remote hosts.

Most probably the messages in your queue are sent by `CRON`, which sends an e-mail every time a job generates some output. However there is only one way to verify it: select some message ID from the output of `/usr/sbin/exim4 -bp` and run:

```
/usr/sbin/exim4 -Mvc <message_id>
```